# Encrypt using SSL when writing syslog messages to a MySQL DB

Tags: database, ssl, rsyslog

I have a rsyslog configuration such that all our servers are logging to centralized logging MySQL DB.  Everything I'm using is pretty default, just installed with `apt-get install rsyslog`.  I have a config file `/etc/rsyslog.d/20-basic.conf`:

```
*.*       :ommysql:127.0.0.1,Syslog,syslogwriter,my_password
```

And this sends syslog logs to the Syslog DB (SystemEvent table) perfectly.  I was just wondering if there was any easy way to use SSL for encryption when sending the logs to the DB.

The rsyslog [doc](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/historical/stunnel.html) has a link to: [rsyslog provides native TLS/SSL encryption](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/historical/rsyslog_tls.html), but it leads to an invalid web page :(

I was wondering if this is even possible out of the box, or will it take quite a bit of hacking.  If someone has some sample template/code or could even point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.  Much appreciated!

Comment: If you're logging to `127.0.0.1` to a MySQL database, have you verified the data isn't going through a local Unix-style socket?  If it is go via a Unix socket and not via a true TCP connection, you won't be able to use SSL anyway.  And even if MySQL supports SSL over Unix sockets, what would you gain?  Anyone on the box who could snoop data going over that socket already has greater access than that.  If you *are* going across a network connection to another server, though, that's totally different...

Comment: @AndrewHenle hm I missed this.  Anyway, sorry I just copied and pasted that from the docs online, but my real config file contains the actual DB address which isn't localhost.  Exactly though, I'm going across a network connection to a centralized logging server.